# How to convert *.RESX XML file to JSON file in C#

Tags: json, xml, c#-7.0

How can I convert *.RESX XML file to JSON file in C#?

I have regular RESX file. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
    <data xml:space="preserve" name="KEY_1">       
        <value>Text A</value>
    </data>
    <data xml:space="preserve" name="KEY_2">       
        <value>Text B</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

I need to convert this file to JSON file:

```
{
  "Texts": [
    {
      "id": "KEY_1",
      "text": "Text A"
    },
    {
      "id": "KEY_2",
      "text": "Text B"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see for conversion is relevant only part with data:

```
    <data xml:space="preserve" name="KEY_1">       
        <value>Text A</value>
    </data>
    <data xml:space="preserve" name="KEY_2">       
        <value>Text B</value>
    </data>
```

Everything else is irrelevant for transformation.

1. **Name** in data attribute XML => is **id** in JSON file.
2. **Value** in XML=> is **text** in JSON file.

EDIT:
I have solution, but I think that it can be done better

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace XMLtoJSON
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            // To convert an XML node contained in string xml into a JSON string 
            var xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test\ClientLocalization.en-US.resx");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlNodeList node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("data");
            foreach (XmlNode item in node)
            {
                var value = item.InnerText.Trim();
                var keyName = item.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "name");
                if (keyName != null)
                {
                    var key = keyName.InnerText.Trim();
                    result.Add(key, value);
                }
            }

            string res = @"{ ""Text"" : [ ";
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                res += "{";
                res += $" \"id\":\"{item.Key}\",\"text\":\"{item.Value}\"";
                res += "},";
            }
            res = res.Remove(res.Length - 1);
            res += @" ]} ";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately thats a very uncompact json... theres a resx to json converter in npm that writes a much more compact json.  Similar to `{"KEY_1":"Text A","KEY_2":"Text B"}` which is a much more preferred structure in the javascript world...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using `XmlDocument`, I would use [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) as it is much more LINQ-friendly.  Use `XElement.Parse` to load the XML, then select the nodes you are interested in and shape them into an anonymous object structure that mirrors the JSON you want.  Finally, use your favorite JSON serializer (such as [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)) to create the JSON from there.  I don't recommend hand-rolling your own JSON, as it is very error prone.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test\ClientLocalization.en-US.resx");

var obj = new
{
    Texts = XElement.Parse(xml)
        .Elements("data")
        .Select(el => new
        {
            id = el.Attribute("name").Value,
            text = el.Element("value").Value.Trim()
        })
        .ToList()
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

// OR:
//JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//string json = jss.Serialize(obj);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZIaCjd

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you the [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) Framework.
It has built-in functions for converting XML to JSON and vice versa.

Example:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
<root>
  <person id='1'>
    <name>Alan</name>
    <url>http://www.google.com</url>
  </person>
  <person id='2'>
    <name>Louis</name>
    <url>http://www.yahoo.com</url>
  </person>
</root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
//{
//  "?xml": {
//    "@version": "1.0",
//    "@standalone": "no"
//  },
//  "root": {
//    "person": [
//      {
//        "@id": "1",
//        "name": "Alan",
//        "url": "http://www.google.com"
//      },
//      {
//        "@id": "2",
//        "name": "Louis",
//        "url": "http://www.yahoo.com"
//      }
//    ]
//  }
//}
```

Comment: While Json.Net does have the ability to convert XML directly to JSON using `SerializeXmlNode`, it would not work well for this particular situation. In this case, the OP wants only a subset of the original XML and wants to rename the `name` attribute and `value` element to `id` and `text` respectively. Also, he wants the data rows to appear in the JSON as a `Texts` array, for which there is no corresponding element in the XML. `SerializeXmlNode` does not provide a means to customize its behavior in this way, so the OP would need to pre-process the XML to get it into the correct shape first.