# ASP.NET Core 7.0 Razor Pages - Create dynamic routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

### Background story about my project

I am trying to add multiple languages to my website. To do that I use locales in the path of the URL to differentiate the various languages. The default website (in English) is located at `http://localhost:5000/` meanwhile the German page is located at `http://localhost:5000/de-de/`. I have made it possible to set a locale that is stored on the session.

Users can change their locale on the website through a form. If a user has set their language to German and they try to visit `http://localhost:5000/` it will redirect to the German page at `http://localhost:5000/de-de`. This works great for redirecting the user to the correct path. Nothing wrong here.

This also works if for example the user has set their locale to German and they try to enter the page: `http://localhost:5000/Pictures` it will redirect them to `http://localhost:5000/de-de/Pictures`. No issues what-so-ever.

At the moment, I have not created any pages for the specific locales. What I have basically done is just set it to redirect to the start page as a fallback. Since `/de-de/` doesn't actually exist in the website, it just loads the start page using: `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/");` in my `Program.cs` file.

### My question

Since I am just redirecting thee user to a fallback page at the moment (due to the fact that there is no `de-de` folder in my `Pages` folder), it only loads the content of the English start page. So if I visit `http://localhost:5000/de-de/Pictures` I am actually seeing the content of `http://localhost:5000/`. This is not good.

Suppose I have two pages in my `Pages` folder. They are called `Index.cshtml` and `Pictures.cshtml`. I can visit them using the default locale (English) at the following URLs: `http://localhost:5000/` and `http://localhost:5000/Pictures`.

**But how can I set it so that it will load the corresponding page, excluding the locale in the URL?** In other words, if a user has set their locale to German and visits `http://localhost:5000/de-de/Pictures`, how can I make it load the HTML from `http://localhost:5000/Pictures`?

I also need this to work for any future pages I created, e.g. `/Videos` or `/About` and so on. It needs to be dynamic.

Do not worry about it being content in English. I can sort that out later. What I just want to achieve is that, without creating a subdirectory at `Pages\de-de`, it should automatically just load the content of the page, without the locale in the URL.

In the future, I want to add 20+ more languages to the website. I do not want to have 20+ folders, each containing the same HTML file. E.g. a folder and file structure like so:

```
Pages
    Index.cshtml
    Pictures.cshtml
    /de-de/
        Index.cshtml
        Pictures.cshtml
    /es-es/
        Index.cshtml
        Pictures.cshtml
    /fr-fr/
        Index.cshtml
        Pictures.cshtml
```

The above example of a folder structure would be difficult to maintain. I simply want two files (`Index.cshtml` and `Pictures.cshtml`) inside my `Pages` directory. And route all other locales to load those files. So if I make a change to the `Pictures.cshtml` file it will update for all locales.

### My middleware

I've set up a middleware called `LocaleMiddleware` which checks for the session variable called `"locale"` and redirects the user accordingly. I'm not sure if there's anything that can be done inside the middleware. All the middleware does is to redirect the user to the correct URL.

The problem I need to resolve is to make that URL load the page content (HTML) from the path without locale inside it.

```
public class LocaleMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LocaleMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Exclude redirects for "/api" and "/auth" paths
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") || context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/auth"))
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        else
        {
            // Regex pattern for URL ([xx-yy])
            string pattern = @"\/([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})";

            // Get locale from session
            string? locale = context.Session.GetString("locale");

            // If no locale, or if locale is default "en-us"
            // Remove any potential locales from URL and redirect them to "root" path
            // E.g. /de-de/Pictures will be reset to /Pictures
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) || locale == "en-us")
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(context.Request.Path, pattern))
                {
                    // Redirect to page without locale in URL
                    string newPath = Regex.Replace(context.Request.Path, pattern, "");
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newPath)) newPath = "/";
                    context.Response.Redirect($"{newPath}");
                    return;
                }
            }

            // If locale is set and is not default "en-us" and locale is not currently in the URL
            // Then it should redirect them to the correct locale URL path
            // E.g. if the user has set locale to "de-de" and loads /Pictures it will redirect to /de-de/Pictures
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) && locale != "en-us" && !context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(locale))
            {
                // Redirect to locale path
                string oldPath = Regex.Replace(context.Request.Path, pattern, "");
                context.Response.Redirect($"/{locale}{oldPath}");
                return;
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

public static class RequestLocaleMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLocaleMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LocaleMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

### Tl/dr:

Basically, if a user has set their locale to `de-de`, I want the URL to be `http://localhost:5000/de-de/Pictures` but load the HTML content from `http://localhost:5000/Pictures`. And for all future paths as well, e.g. `/Videos`, `/Contact`.

In other words the logic would be:

```
1. Check if the URL path matches Regex pattern for locales [xx-yy]
2. If it does, setup a router to load HTML from the path EXCLUDING the locale
```

Where and how can I do this? In which files do I setup routing for that? And it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Have a look at the `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` described in my article here: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/348/razor-pages-localisation-seo-friendly-urls

Comment: So how does those "Cultures" work? Where are they stored? On my website, for all users I am storing their culture/locale (e.g. "en-gb") in a session variable. Maybe your approach is better than my own middleware to forward users to the correct path. Or maybe a mix of them. Keep my middleware as it is, but add some parts of your code to display the page. Is there any way to make your code work with mine? I do not use any "Culture" variables. I simply set locale to session. I already have the redirects working. I just need to make e.g. /de-de/Pictures load the content from /Pictures.

Comment: Also, how did you switch the language? I Was planning on making JSON files containing each language, e.g. "English.json", "French.json", "German.json". And depending on the user's Locale, I load the correct language file, and pass it to the page frontend where I can print out values from the file.

Comment: I did a series of articles on localization. The answers to all your questions should be covered in them: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/category/41/localization. Start at the bottom of the list and work your way up.

Comment: In .net projects ,you could try with .resx(resource files )  for different languages

Comment: @MikeBrind - I have read your articles about `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` but it seems to me that you can call an arbitrary URL with a dummy culture and not get a proper 404? E.g. https://localhost/dummy-dummy/Pictures or https://localhost/de-de/Pictures/DummyPage

Answer (score 1):

There's build-in support for localization in asp.net core ,you could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0) related

based on the doc and Mike Brind's article,

a minimal example here:

```
public class CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;

            for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
            {
                var selector = model.Selectors[i];

                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        //modify -1 to 1 here
                        Order = 1,
                        Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{culture?}", selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options=> {
    options.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention()); 
});

builder.Services.AddLocalization();
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-us", "zh-cn" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());
});
```

....

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

PageModel:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer<MyPageModel> _localizer;

        public MyPageModel(IStringLocalizer<MyPageModel> localizer) 
        {
            _localizer = localizer;
        }
        
        [FromRoute]
        public string? culture { get; set; }

        public string? Hi { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Hi = _localizer["Hi"];
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
            {
                Response.Cookies.Append(
             CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
             CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
             new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });
            }
            
   
        }
    }
```

Page:

@Model.Hi;

Resource files:
[image]

MyProject:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Modify resource file:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Is there any way to have the language files in .JSON files? I plan on outsourcing some of the translations and it would be very easy for me to send them a .JSON file in English, ask them to translate it, and send it back to me so I can just import it. Or are those resource files the same thing? It's a file I can just copy (e.g. the English file) and send to someone and they can edit it without Visual Studio? Also I never worked with models and stuff, I just switched over from Node.js. That first code example, where do I place it? Should I just make a folder named "Models"?

Comment: Hi,@Olote,please check what i've updated,you could open resx file with txt editor,you would found it's in xml and you could modify it directly without vs.

Comment: The document related with work with resx files programmatically:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/work-with-resx-files-programmatically

Comment: where do I place it? Should I just make a folder named "Models"--just create a class name of  CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention unter the directory of your project,classesin models is usually for your business codes

Comment: A case related with convert resx to json :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631098/how-to-convert-resx-xml-file-to-json-file-in-c-sharp