# How to display text in Angular template from resource file (.rsx) in a ASP.NET Web application?

Tags: asp.net, angular, resx

I'm combining Angular 14 with a legacy ASP.NET Web application and we have static texts in a resource file (.rsx) in a folder outside of Angular.

I need to display those texts in a component's template (inside Angular). How can I do to achieve that?

Comment: Would say that the Angular app can't directly access the .resx file. More like you need to build an API to get the values from the resx file (based on selected culture), and the Angular app call that API.

Comment: Hmm then I guess it already exists (i'm not a backend-developer) because before they used angularJS (I'm rewriting it to latest Angular) and they managed to display the texts. But I'm not sure how to do the same in latest Angular..

Comment: Ah I found it and know how to access it! :) thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, it is likely that you need to implement an API to get the resources file's value and return it as a JSON object/dictionary.

You can refer to [`ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo, Boolean, Boolean)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset?view=netframework-4.8.1) to retrieve the resource values.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Resources;

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetResources")]
public ActionResult GetResources(string? languageCode)
{
    var rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(NumberResources)); // Replace `NumberResources` with your Resource name

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(languageCode))
        languageCode = "en-US";

    ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languageCode),
                                         true, false);
    if (rs == null)
    {
        // Handle if resource file not found
        throw BadRequest("Resource not found");
    }

    var dictionary = resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
        .ToDictionary(r => r.Key.ToString(),
            r => r.Value.ToString());

    return Json(dictionary, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

For the Angular side, implement the service to call the API.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LanguageService {
  constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getLanguage(languageCode: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`<API Domain>/<Controller path>/GetResources?languageCode=${languageCode}`);
  }
}
```

Caller

```
constructor (private languageService: LanguageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.languageService.getLanguages(/* languageCode */)
    .subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don t think there is a ready to use solution for this, think its best if you provide a dynamic/static generated json that you load in you translation module.

something that looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47640150/6236935)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I found that an API already existed so I can access the values from there.